# Failing to create devices with minor number 0 and 1

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, device

I am failing to create two device nodes with minor number 0 and 1 under /proc. device_create creates the first device with minor number 0, but how do I create the second device with minor number 1?

```
static int __init my_driver_init (void) {
    int result;
    int major;
    printk("In init module");

    result = alloc_chrdev_region(&dev, 0, 2, mydev_name);
    if (result<0)
     return result;

    major = MAJOR(dev);

    printk("The device is registered by Major no: %d\n", major);
    my_driver_cdev = cdev_alloc();
   cdev_init (my_driver_cdev, &my_driver_fops);
    my_driver_cdev->owner = THIS_MODULE;
    result = cdev_add(my_driver_cdev, 0, 2);
    if (result<0){
      printk("Error in registering the module\n");
      unregister_chrdev_region(dev, 2);
      return result;
    }

    printk(KERN_INFO "my_driver: %d\n",__LINE__);

    my_driver_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE,mydev_name);
    if (IS_ERR(my_driver_class)) {
            printk(KERN_ERR "Error creating my_driver class.\n");
            result = PTR_ERR(my_driver_class);
            cdev_del(my_driver_cdev);
            unregister_chrdev_region(dev, 2);
            return -1;
    }
  device_create(my_driver_class,NULL,dev,NULL,"my_driver%d",0);

  printk(KERN_INFO "my_driver: %d\n",__LINE__);
```

}

Adding the below line does not create the second device with minor number 1.

```
device_create(my_driver_class,NULL,dev,NULL,"my_driver%d",1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fourth argument of device_create should be major number and minor (in dev) using which device file will be created. In your case fourth argument is always same, you need to provide the next minor number to the device_create. You can write code like this:

```
    for (minor = 0; minor < 2; minor++) 
         device_create(my_driver_class,NULL,MKDEV(major, minor),NULL,"my_driver%d",minor);
```